# How does steam opens before the game?

Tags: steam

How does steam open when I try to open a game outside of steam? 
How does steam set ID for games ? how can they change an already compiled game?
What is this called? How can I learn it? 
I searched for a week now I cant seem to find anything.
Please a help me with a keyword I can help or an article or tutorial or anything really.
(in any programming language.)

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol

Comment: @Claies how can I open my app like steam and torrent (magnet link) ? this is exaclty what I needed

Comment: what is this called? where Can I read about it?

Comment: it's called a browser helper object, but the steam version is one specially designed and registered in conjunction with Microsoft.  Unless you have some commercial need, it is unlikely that you would be able to develop an app of this nature, since it requires in depth knowledge of internal windows APIs and the registry.  This is not open source software.

Answer (score 1):

The direct access on your desktop to the game are URLs that link to steam and use the game ID as parameter indicating which game to open, example steam://rungameid/730 will launch steam and open CS:GO, if you want to launch a game without steam, go to your library folder and search for the .exe of the game but probably wont work because it will tell you to launch steam first.

The rest of the questions don't make any sense, steam is also a form of DRM so game developers put the steam code on their games by themselves.